# Sorting a two-dimensional array doesn't sort in the right order

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to sort a two-dimensional array based on the second column, here is the array:

```
[1.1, 60.0]
[1.2, 66.66]
[1.3, -1.0]
[1.4, 50.0]
[1.5, 100.0]
[2.1, -1.0]
[2.2, -1.0]
[2.3, -1.0]
```

I looked into sorting mutli-dimensional arrays and created the following code:

```
    private void sortKnowledgeScores(double[][] knowledgescores){
    Arrays.sort(knowledgescores, new Comparator<double[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
            double itemOne = o1[1];
            double itemTwo = o2[1];
            // sort on item id
            if(itemOne < itemTwo){
                return (int) itemOne;
            }
            return (int) itemIdTwo;
        }
```

This rearranges the array to this:

```
[2.3, -1.0]
[2.2, -1.0]
[2.1, -1.0]
[1.3, -1.0]
[1.1, 60.0]
[1.2, 66.66]
[1.4, 50.0]
[1.5, 100.0]
```

Which is correct for the first three values however it puts 50 below 60 and 60.66. How can I adjust my sortKnowledgeScores function to sort my array based on the first column in ascending order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparator should return 1,0,-1 (as bigger, equel, less).

Generally, if the compare function return positive result the first element is bigger, 0 they equal and negative result mean the second obj is bigger.

**You returning the values and not the compare result.**

You can look at this [doc](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-interface-java/)

You need to change your code to:

```
public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
        return (int) o1[1] - o2[1];
 }
```

As @Mick point out - notice that index you using: index 0 is for the first column and index 1 is for the second

Comment: o1[0] - o2[0] , I guess

Comment: that depend on the OP - I know he said "first" col which mean index 0 but on the code and the explain he talk about the second col so I keep the `1` index here. That is good comment if he actually mean that but I don't think this was his issue

Comment: That's my bad, I meant the second column which would have an index of 1

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're using the wrong index. The first element in an array is at index 0

You can use the Comparator-Factory `Comparator.comparingDouble`:

```java
Comparator.comparingDouble(array -> array[0])
```

```java
Arrays.sort(knowledgescores, Comparator.comparingDouble(array -> array[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You compare the elements with index "1". This translates to the second column. You should use index "0" if sorting should consider the first column.

Plus - as already mentioned - the compare method works like this:

*Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.*